# Sound fades out, but does not fade in -- why?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I think I understand the main concept of Web Audio API, as well as how sounds are working in general. And even though I managed to make the sound *"fade out"*, I cannot figure out, why it is not *"fading in"* in the following snippet I wrote to represent the problem:

```js
(function ()
{
    'use strict';
    var context = new AudioContext(),
        wave = context.createOscillator(),
        gain = context.createGain(),
        ZERO = 0.000001;

    wave.connect(gain);
    gain.connect(context.destination);

    wave.type = 'sine';
    wave.frequency.value = 200;
    gain.gain.value = ZERO;

    wave.start(context.currentTime);

    gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1.00, 1.0);
    gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(ZERO, 3.0);
})();
```

***NOTE:*** The same problem appeared on Firefox (Linux) and Chrome (Windows) too

Comment: I've also observed the same problem (I think) with `linearRampToValueAtTime` fade-in, so it's at least not an exponential-specific problem. Also, since you seem to have a complete runnable example here (thanks!), would you mind editing it into a Stack Snippet so we can run and edit it directly  on the page?

Comment: @apsillers yepp, I've also tested this with the `linear` version, and as you stated => same result. I hope I converted the above code correctly to Stack Snippet (I've never used that so far, thanks for the heads up ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing your `gain.gain.value = ZERO` line with:

```
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(ZERO, 0);
```

will fix the problem.

The rationale is in the [actual specification](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-exponentialRampToValueAtTime-void-float-value-double-endTime) of the `exponentialRampToValueAtTime()` function:

> Schedules an exponential continuous change in parameter value from the previous scheduled parameter value to the given value

So, if there's no previous scheduled parameter value (only a fixed value) then the function cannot interpolate.  The same applies to the `linearRampToValueAtTime` function.

This may also be useful from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam):

> `AudioParam.value` ... Though it can be set, any modifications happening while there are automation events scheduled — that is events scheduled using the methods of the AudioParam — are ignored, without raising any exception

Comment: Umm.. yepp.. it looks like this is fixing the problem.. it is very curious, indeed!

Answer (score 3):

You need to

```
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(ZERO, 0);
```

because just setting

```
gain.gain.value = ZERO;
```

does not set a schedule point in the AudioParam scheduler - so it's scheduling from the last know schedule point (which is the default value of 1 at time=0).  Mixing setting .value and scheduling does not tend to work well; I've had an article 75% written about this for a long time, and just haven't gotten it released.

Comment: Hi Chris - have an upvote for your work on editing the spec :)  I really must finish that TB-303 emulator that I started...

Comment: I hadn't, dammit! :p   My problem was I started back when the spec was immature, and never got over my frustrations with how to properly emulate an analog EG. ;)